# Ideal Data Structure to answer IsOn(i) and Toggle(i, j) - should be better than HashSet

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a question I was asked recently in an interview. I came up with a decent solution, but was told by my interviewer there is a better one.

Imagine there are n light bulbs (or whatever binary thingy of your choice..) and initially they are all off. Design an approach to answer in ideal time ans space complexity two queries:

(1) IsOn(i) - return true if element 'i' is on

(2) Toggle(i, j) - change the state of all elements in the range [i,j] (inclusive).

1. Initial solution: an array. IsOn in O(1), Toggle in O(j - i), but O(N) space complexity.
2. Better solution: Hashset that holds all elements which are on. IsOn is still O(1), Toggle is still O(j - i), but much better space complexity.

I was told that I should find a better solution, one that has to do with storing the **ranges** of the elements which are on - but I struggle to understand it.

Comment: Both operations can be done in O(log n). I don't remember the name of the data structure right now.

Comment: Most probably it's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by a segment tree with lazy propagation. The algorithm would be as follow

1. initially the array would be filled with 0
2. update(i, j) would toggle the value in the range i to j. This can be done in O(nlogn) using lazy propagation
3. Query(l) would tell us the value at the index [l,l]

Time complexity O(nlogn) to build the tree, and O(logn) for query and update

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm having troubles finding good explanations about this topic. Can you direct me to one?

Comment: sure you should take a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lazy-propagation-in-segment-tree/

Comment: Why is it better than using a hash map? Here you say you get update(i, j) in O(nlogn) but with hash map it's O(j-i) which is not worse than O(n).

Comment: @marvel308
What troubles me is that space complexity - if I understand the 'segment tree' correctly, it's space complexity is double than our original array (so 2N), and supporting the 'lazy' approach requires another array of size N.
This is a lot of space, considering the fact that our very first solution, the simple array, was disqualified for having O(N) space complexity!


However, I do understand how the interval tree, while not improving space complexity, allows log(n) for both operations, which is what I wanted.